# What do white-space and -o-pre-wrap do in CSS?

Tags: css

I need some help understanding this bit of code

```
pre 
{ 
    white-space: pre; 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    width: 800px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

What's with all the different keywords following `white-space:` ?

What does `white-space: -o-pre-wrap;`  do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its for different browsers.

> The white-space property specifies how
>   white-space inside an element is
>   handled.

Read [White space: the 'white-space' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop)

> Mozilla supports a number of
>   extensions to CSS that are prefixed
>   with -moz-.

Read [Mozilla CSS Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions?PHPSESSID=a3c92fb0792303cea207d1bb7bc693fa)

But I don't know why two styles rules are applied for white-space property, pre and pre-wrap.

-o is for Opera.

[**Browser proprietary CSS extensions and DOM node prefixes**](http://www.codestyle.org/javascript/dom/css/CSS3ExtensionStyles.shtml)

Comment: I think one may be just for Mozilla and the other is for all other browsers?